# BATCH list files in path

Tags: batch-file

I have the following:

```
@echo off
set mypath= 
call :treeProcess
goto :eof

:treeProcess
setlocal
for %%f in (*) do echo %mypath%%%f
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    set mypath=%mypath%%%d\
    cd %%d
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..
)
endlocal
pause
exit /b
```

I would like to know how to change the directory to something like W:\ instead of listing the files where this BATCH file is saved. I also would like to know how to list the times each file was created/modified

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly? please provide input and output examples? I'm sure there's a simpler solution.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416722/batch-file-to-count-files-in-a-in-subdirectories/39420247#39420247)'s an answer that counts files and dirs using the same approach. Note that since it changes an env var from within a `for` loop, you must use [delayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). As for timestamp you can use [`%~t1`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: To change the directory you have to type out the path to the file/folder you want to parse. Hint: look at the `*` in the code

Comment: If you want to change the directory you either choose `pushd <path>` or `cd /d <path>`

Comment: hi.  i now have: dir "M\folder1\folder2\*.jpg"
dir "M:\folder1\folder2\*.pdf"  looks good so far.  but i want to specify the 2 filetypes in 1 single line, because my ultimate goal is to output the list/results into a "TEST.txt" file.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dir /A:-D /T:C "M:\Path\To\*jpg" "M:\Path\To\*pdf" > "M:\Path\To\Outputfile.txt"
```

It creates `Outputfile.txt` which will contain a list of all the `pdf` and `jpg` files in the dir you specify.

Creation date/times included. Not sure about modified dates/times though.

Check out [this link](https://www.windows-commandline.com/get-file-creation-date-time/) and [this link](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html).